# animation using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I need to animate a square, just like move around with in a div.
Its should never stop until i meet a condition.

Please help me how to write this.. I could use some example...

Answer (score 2):

The [jQuery docs](http://docs.jquery.com/Core/queue) has an example of an animation queue that moves a square around.

Answer (score 0):

You may get more help if you were to tell how it should be animated, or give an example of what you've tried so far.